# chipmunk-spaceManager collision detection

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, collision, chipmunk

I can't find solution for one type of collision.

I have few cpShapes in the space and some block.

The goal is detect collision between shapes and block. But, block won't have behavior like cpShape. So shapes can move cross block borders. And we should just detect collisions but not stop movement of shapes cross block.

Main goal is detect when all shapes inside or outside of block

Answer (score 0):

Make the block be a sensor shape.